# Laravel: Route params not working

Tags: laravel

I switched my laravel project to my live server today and the type hinting of the routing parameters doesn't work anymore. The parameter is recognized correctly, but as soon as I add the type hinting I receive null.

The Post with the id 1 exists, I double checked that already, so I assume some of the server settings being wrong.

Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong?

Route:

```
Route::get('post/{post}', 'PostController@show');
```

Server call:

```
http://my-server/post/1
```

PostController:

```
public function show(Post $post){
  dd($post); //null
}

public function show($post){
  dd($post); //1
}
```

Comment: Triple check :) just try doing `dd($post->all()->pluck('id'));` on the **live server** what does that show?

Comment: Which version of Laravel do you use? Also, can you share your model `Post`?

Comment: dd($post->all()->pluck('id')); has the output: [ 0 => 1] and I am using laravel 5.5.40 on PHP 7.2.3

Comment: are you using windows os in local?

Comment: In your kernel.php do you have `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class`? I bet you just have different code on live vs local. SubstituteBindings has nothing to do with web-server setup.

Comment: The kernel bindings were ok, but you pushed me into the right direction. Seems like Filezilla was messing up the upload. After uploading all files once again everything is working fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding another parameter such as $id. Since show is default laravel function just try it as resource controller route or try below method method

```
public function show(Post $post, $id){
  dd($id); //It will return the id
}
```